# How to make SwitchListTile Icon clickable?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to make the `secondary` property of the `SwitchListTile` tapable? In this case, an `icon` is used:

```
SwitchListTile(
  title: const Text('Lights'),
  value: _lights,
  onChanged: (bool value) { setState(() { _lights = value; }); },
  secondary: const Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline), //can this be selected?
)
```

Ideally, instead of creating another widget, I would like to use the `Icon` in the `secondary` property to display a message when the user selects it.

Currently when the icon, or entire widget is selected, the switch is toggled. What is the best way to handle this action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `Icon` inside `InkWell` to handle the tap :

```
      secondary: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  print("click light");
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
              ),
```

More info here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html

Comment: Super simple, don't know why I didn't think about inkwell. Coupled with this [Alert dialogue turtorial](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/06/flutter-event-alert-with-pop-up.html) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your Icon in an IconButton.

```
SwitchListTile(
  title: const Text('Lights'),
  value: _lights,
  onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _lights = value),
  secondary: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
)
```